# Protobuf extension_count returning zero

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I'm currently using protobuf for a project (C++), when I invoke field_count, it correctly returns 5 fields, for that message, but 0 for extensions. I did extend that message, on another file, something along these lines:

File A:

```
package alpha.proto;

message msg { 
    optional ping ping_field = 10;
    optional pong pong_field = 20;

    extensions 100 to max;
}
```

File B:

```
package beta.proto;

import "fileA.proto";

message delta_request {
    required int32 num = 10
}

extend alpha.proto.msg {
    optional delta_request delta_request_field = 110;
}
```

...

Does anyone know what the cause for returning zero as extension_count could be? Thank you.

Comment: Which descriptor were you calling extension_count on?  Because you declared the extension at the top level, it would be in the `FileDescriptor`, not the `Descriptor`

Comment: Let me check, thx for the reply...

Comment: I tried using the FileDescriptor, but it also did not return the extensions present on file B, package beta.proto.

Is it because I'm naming packages in File A as one thing, and as another in File B?

Do I need to name the package as alpha.proto in file B?

Very confused here...